# 2005 Hyundai Santa Fe Won't Start

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, hyundai, santa-fe

I have an '05 Santa Fe with the 2.7L engine that won't start. I bought it this way. Was told that car died and was towed home. Found that alternator was bad. While they were replacing alternator they sparked the ratchet against the block.

Symptoms: cranks but no start.

Checked fuel pressure. Good. (Also tried a little starting fluid still no go)

Noid light tested injectors: good

Spark tested the coil pack. Good.

Tested all relays and fuses. Good.

Pulled ECU to check for moistened or shorts. No noticeable signs.

Pulled the top cover of timing belt loose to verify belt didn't snap.

Next thinking about pulling all covers to check timing marks...

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Crank and/or cam sensor will cause a crank no start scenario. Did you test for spark at the plug to verify it's actually firing?  It sounds like it's not if it won't try to run with fuel put directly in the cylinder. This would indicate the sensor not sending the data to the computer to tell it where the cam or crank position is at, which helps determine when it would fire the plugs. Also, I've seen some vehicles that don't throw an engine light code for these sensors, but some do.